# BigTable checkAndMutate atomicity

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

What is the behaviour of the [*checkAndMutate*](https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Table.html#checkAndMutate-byte:A-byte:A-) function? Let's say I need to get row content before applying *checkAndMutate*. Is there a chance to retrieve *stale* data from BigTable? If there is no chance to retrieve stale data, is my thinking good:

1. Fetch row content by key,
2. Modify row content in application,
3. Apply *checkAndMutate* function on row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CheckAndMutate is atomic.  Here is the API definition.  There is a chance that there was a change between step #1 and #3.  Your checkAndMutate should ensure that the timestamp for the cells you care about are the same values as #3 to ensure that you're updating the same data that you read.

Comment: That was exactly my thoughts, just wanted to make sure. Thanks!